# UIWebVIew Javascript Document.location

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, console, document

I have been unable to get my UIWebView to change location based in javascript. While this may seem a bit redundant, it is necessary because the client's website stores a cookie when document.location is known. However, when I try accessing the next part of his site, it will not open.

Here is the code

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.location = 'http://www.nextLink.com'"];
```

However, this doesn't seem to have done anything. Also the document.write method works!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `window.location` instead?